# asp.net mvc close previous session for same user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

Hi i need to close previous session for same user. If user logon on computer A and then logon on B i must close session for A.
I have no even any ideas to do it :(
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new session

```
Session.Abandon();
```

And depending on the inner workings of your application also logout your user. This is of course not needed if you store logged in user in Session. It will get abandoned with the first call anyway.

### Edit

If you need to access other sessions of the same user then you will have to resort to other session state modes than InProc. In your case a DB state mode would do the trick. Check this [MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) about it.

You will have to create a separate table like:

```
create table UserSession
(
    UserID int not null
        references dbo.User(UserID),
    SessionID varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (UserID, SessionID)
)
go
```

When a user logs in you will have to:

1. Update UserSession tabel and either remove existing user sessions.
2. Add current session.

When user logs out you simply remove the record from `UserSession` table.

You probably have a custom `IHttpModule` for your authentication. This particular module should check whether a record exists for the current session. If it doesn't it should logout the user and redirect to a page that says something like *You've logged in at some other place*.

> **Table comment:** Every user can have several sessions in the table since they may get disconnected or they may simply close their browsers before logging out. Hence primary key on both fields.

Comment: but have i can access to previous session ? i dont get it, sorry

Comment: @Sanja Melnichuk: You will have to do this in application A if it detects that user has logged in somewhere else. If you'd like to access various sessions you'll have to resort to other session state management (like DB session). You could manually access other user sessions using a DB.

Comment: You mean store some uuid to db and then get it for user and close session that associated with that uuid ? Thanks

Comment: @Sanja Melnichuk: Check my Edit.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik , , i am new to sessions.  I have the same requirment , How can i clear user's previous sessions using that table , can we clear a session with session Id